# Cleanest way to set many variables in python

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a cleaner way of setting up many configuration methods and variables.  Can this be done in a cleaner more pythonic way?  I thought about a dictionary but was not sure if that is best practice.

```
script_name = sys.argv[0].split('.')[0]                                         
now = datetime.datetime.today()                                                 
today = datetime.date.today()                                                   
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)                                            
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)                                                   
config_file = '%s/%s_config.ini' % (ini_path, target_os)                        
config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                            
config.read(config_file)                                                        
config.sections()                                                               
cwd = os.getcwd()                                                               
base_dir = config.get('root_dir', 'dir')                                        
file_name = 'fakeappname.%s.%s.log' % (target_os, today)                            
log_file = os.path.join(cwd, file_name)                                         
log_key = log_file.split('/')[-1]                                               
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, 'w', 'utf-8')                           
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)                                                  
formatter = logging.Formatter(                                                  
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s -'                    
    ' {0}'.format(socket.gethostname()))                                        
handler.setFormatter(formatter)                                                 
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure, I guess I just don't like the one variable per line, I was wondering if there is a better way to manage setting all these. Perhaps a module I overlooked? If I had 30 more is it best practice to set one per line?

Comment: Unless the data and variables that you're assigning follow the same general pattern, there isn't much you can do. There isn't enough consistency here to be able to generalize.

Comment: Some of these things are related, but a lot of them aren't. I'm still not sure that I understand the problem.

Comment: You can write the constants in CAPITAL LETTERS. You can also separate the vars etc in categories, like `# general definitions` for `script_name`and `base_dir`, `# Log definitions` for `logger`etc., it's easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: The shown code looks as if it contains a few distinct activities (prepare logging, read config, build file paths). Using and setting variables in this way is usually right (although writing functions for the activities is usually better so that some variables can be kept local if not further needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of code that can be executed inline like instead of:

```py
cwd = os.getcwd()                                                                                          
log_file = os.path.join(cwd, file_name)
log_key = log_file.split('/')[-1]
```

you can do

```py
log_key = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name).split('/')[-1]
```

Things like that would require you to add comments for explanation, which you should probably be doing anyway.